# What is the purpose of pythonwrapper, and how can I distinguish it from an executable Python interpreter?

Tags: macos, python, symlink

I have a Bourne script that takes a Python command (Python interpreter and arguments) and reroutes it to a custom Python interpreter. I want to make sure that modules that would be on the path of the original interpreter are put on the path of the custom interpreter. Customers have indicated that they are unwilling to abandon Python 2, so if possible, I want to continue to support it.

The path to the interpreter that is passed to the script may be either a genuine path or as a symlink. I want to determine the path to the associated `lib/site-packages` directory so that I can put it on the Python path (via `PYTHONPATH`). I have written code that uses `readlink` (without option flags) to recursively follow symlinks until it encounters a genuine (executable) file. It works fine when I pass "`python3`" to the script. However, when I pass in "`python`" (which points to Python 2 on my system), the resolution goes beyond `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7` to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/pythonwrapper.app/Contents/MacOS/pythonwrapper`. If I try to execute that `pythonwrapper` file, I get this output:

```
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/pythonwrapper.app/Contents/MacOS/pythonwrapper
2022-03-18 11:33:30.863 pythonwrapper[85401:13062358] pythonwrapper is not supposed to be executed directly. Exiting.
```

Ideally, if I found that the next link in the chain of symlinks was a file like this, I would stop at the previous link. However, I can't find any documentation or forum questions about this "`pythonwrapper`" file. Any of the following knowledge would help me write special logic that would help me stop at the previous link:

- something about the purpose of `pythonwrapper`
- whether it's only designed for Python 2, and would not appear in a Python 3 installation
- whether it always has the name "`pythonwrapper`"

I suppose it would be possible for me to check at each point to see whether there is a `lib/site-packages` directory one directory up, especially since that's what I'm ultimately interested in, but I'm not sure whether that's the best way to proceed.

Comment: Start by explaining what you are trying to do not how you are implementing this. Also python 2.7 has not been supported by python for a couple of years so assume it is broken and only use it if you fully understand why you are using it.

Comment: I added an initial paragraph that addresses these points.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, Alan - one thing extra if you list the specific version of macOS you test on, we often can be more detailed in an answer. I’ve got a general answer on why this is fragile and potentially a bad plan, but maybe you have a limited time or OS range you need to support?

Comment: @bmike, I don't have a limited time or OS range. I'm testing on Monterey/12.1 right now, but I plan to upgrade soon. I suspected that it would be a fragile approach, and would be glad to hear your explanation.

Comment: 12.3 is when python 2 is removed so if you can work past that, you’re past the main change period. If you package the tool, then you can test back as far as you care to support.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has an interesting stance on all scripting languages and it’s summarized in the instructions when they deprecated python.

> If your software depends on scripting languages, it’s recommended that you bundle the runtime within the app.

The best answer I can give you is to make an app that bundles the exact version of the tool and not assume `/System` will not get patched or changed even on non-Monterey operating systems.

Should any large security issue arrive and Apple will not hesitate to pull or block deprecated API/SDK.

Initially this is extra work for you, but ultimately you have full control over packages and library changes and this may even save time in the long run on your support and break/fix efforts by controlling your runtime environment more closely.

We likely will chose this version as our preferred one but are evaluating a couple other options at work:

- https://github.com/macadmins/python

I do believe consultants will have lucrative opportunities to support people that want python 2 to continue in their environment and also want to have reliable support and manage risk of an outage or security event.